# sending a string from java to R

Tags: java, linux, r, string, putty

i want to take a string in from a java program i am running and send that string to a R program that i have written to do some DNA analysis for a school project.

```
inputvec <- vector() #Variable to hold entire sequence
codonSeparator <- vector() #Vector to hold created substrings(codons)
sequences <- matrix()
```

file = "DNA.txt" will be replaced with a variable that takes in the file name from the java program.

```
inputVec <- scan(file = "DNA.txt", what = "character", sep = "", blank.lines.sk$
inputVec <- toupper(inputVec)                   #change sequence string into al$
inputVec <- paste(inputVec, sep="", collapse="")      #incase of extra lines, d$
codonSeparator <- substring(inputVec, seq(1,nchar(inputVec),3),seq(3,nchar(inpu$

counter <- 0
maxLen <- 0
bool <- FALSE



for(i in 1:length(codonSeparator)){
 if(codonSeparator[i] == "TAC"){bool = TRUE}
        if(bool == TRUE){
                counter <- counter + 1
        }
        if(codonSeparator[i] == "ACG"){
                bool <- FALSE
                if(counter > maxLen){maxLen <- counter}
                counter <- 0
        }
}

lst <- list()
seqHolder <- rep(NA, maxLen)
holderCount <- 1
rCount <- 1

for(i in 1:length(codonSeparator)){
        if(codonSeparator[i] == "TAC"){bool = TRUE}
        if(bool == TRUE){
                seqHolder[holderCount] <- codonSeparator[i]

 }
        if(codonSeparator[i] == "ACG"){
                if(bool){
                        lst[rCount] <- list(seqHolder)
                        seqHolder <- rep(NA, maxLen)
                        rCount <- rCount + 1
                }
                bool <- FALSE
                holderCount <- 1
        }
 if(bool == TRUE){holderCount <- holderCount + 1}
}

sequences <- do.call(rbind,lst)
```

I will basically be calling this code and sending in the string from a java program that i have created. How can i call the R program and send in a string from java? Also i am running these programs on a linux server through puTTY.

Answer (score 1):

With the nice concept called `socket`s. With sockets, you can send data between two programs. Here are some sources:

- [Socket programming in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/make.socket.html)
- [Socket programming in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

Or, you can try something nicer: Redis pub/sub mechanism. Resources:

- [Redis pub/sub documentation](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub)
- [Redis client for R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rredis/index.html)
- [Redis pub/sub example in Java](http://basrikahveci.com/a-simple-jedis-publish-subscribe-example/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to utilize a communication library for coupling your programs, either [zeromq](http://zeromq.org) or [nanomsg](http://nanomsg.org).

Both of them have java and R bindings.